# CasperJS - WaitForSelectors() not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a problem with a simple demo script in CasperJS, it is running in Ubuntu server with phantomjs v1.9.8 and casperjs v1.1.4.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({ 
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
         loadImages:  false,        // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
         loadPlugins: true,         // use these settings
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    },
    verbose: true
});
casper.options.viewportSize = {
    width: 1890, 
    height: 993
}; // Desktop IML
casper.options.waitTimeout = 60000;


var path = "https://www.burgerkingdelivers.co.uk/home",
    pathLogin = "https://www.burgerkingdelivers.co.uk/login";
// Test => casper.cli.get(i);

casper.start(path, function(){
    this.echo("\n||Mode Matrix ON||\n");
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("\nPath laoded: " + path + "\n");  
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.waitForSelector('li[qa-label="navLinksSignIn"]');
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.click('li[qa-label="navLinksSignIn"]');
    this.echo("\nYou are here: " + this.getCurrentUrl() + "\n");  
});

casper.then(function(){
    // TODO 
    this.waitForSelector('form[qa-label="signIn"]');
    this.echo("\nLogin form loaded.\n");
});
//test
casper.then(function(){
    this.capture('testForm.png', {
        top: 50,
        left: 50,
        width: this.options.viewportSize.width,
        height: this.options.viewportSize.height
    });
});
casper.then(function(){
    if (this.exists('form[qa-label="signIn"]'))
        this.echo("Exist...");
    this.fillSelectors('form[qa-label="signIn"]', { 
        'input[type="email"]': '<<EMAIL>>',
        'input[type="password"]': '<<PASS>>'
    }, true);
});

//test
casper.then(function(){
    this.capture('testFields.png', {
        top: 50,
        left: 50,
        width: this.options.viewportSize.width,
        height: this.options.viewportSize.height
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.echo("\nSend form\n");  
    this.click('button[qa-label="SignInButton"]');
});
casper.wait(1000, function() {
    this.echo("\nWait for load homepage logged.\n");
});
//test
casper.then(function(){
    this.capture('testLogin.png', {
        top: 50,
        left: 50,
        width: this.options.viewportSize.width,
        height: this.options.viewportSize.height
    });
});


casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("\nYou are here: " + this.getCurrentUrl() + "\n");  
});
// require('utils').dump(JSON.parse(this.getPageContent()));

casper.run();
```

I have searched any solution (increase timeout, add wait() before waitForSelector()...) but without solution.

This same code run ok in my localhost with a wamp server :S

Any idea why it is not succeeded in amazonaws?

Regards!

Comment: What does your log say?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus solvented! I found this issue in casperjs github
https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/1880
It works!
Thanks ^^